# Why System.IO.Filestream read/copy from external source to local destination causing "not responding" in windows application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating an application that has file/folder copy function. When copying from local drive `(e.g c:\source)` to local drive `(e.g d:\destination\)` the application is working fine.

But when I copy file from network drive `(e.g \\192.168.0.2\source)` to local drive `(e.g d:\destination)` the application triggers not responding. Its normal when copying large files becomes unresponsive then later the application continues until completion. In my case copying from `external (network)` drive to `local drive` the application triggers "Not Responding". When I check the destination some files where copied but the application stops running.

I'm using `System.IO.Filestream read/write` method to copy files.

Below is my code for copying files:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
        'set folder to copy files
        Dim sourcePath As String
        Dim destinationPath As String

        'where X:\ is a mapped network drive and D:\ is a local drive
        sourcePath = "X:\copyfiles\" 
        destinationPath = "D:\destination\" 

        'get directory from source 
        For Each sourceDirectory As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDirectory.Replace(sourcePath, destinationPath))
        Next

        'Copy all the files
        For Each sourceFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            CopyFile(sourceFile, sourceFile.Replace(sourcePath, destinationPath))
        Next
        MsgBox("Copy Successful", vbOKOnly, "Message")
    End Sub

    'define buffer size
    Private Const CopyBufferSize As Integer = (64 * 1024)

    'System.IO.Filestream read/write files
    Private Shared Sub CopyFile(ByVal src As String, ByVal dest As String)
        Dim outputFile = File.OpenWrite(dest)
        Dim inputFile = File.OpenRead(src)
        outputFile.SetLength(inputFile.Length)
        Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte((CopyBufferSize) - 1) {}
        Dim bytesRead As Integer

        While (inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, CopyBufferSize) <> 0)
            outputFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there anything I can do to improve the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not valid for the c# tag!

Comment: @cramopy i removed the tag already. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because copying a file over the network has more latency and can be indeed slower than copying from and to a local drive.

What you need is *multi-threading*. That is, your file can be sent to your network location while the UI thread isn't blocked until the whole file has been completely sent.

If you're not used with multi-threading, probably you can start with [`BackgroundWorker` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to queue a work in a separate thread.

Comment: i tried copying from local source to network drive its fine. just when copying from external to local it triggers "Not reponding" in my windows application

Comment: @AlexNewbie If you've already understood what I'm trying to show you in my answer, you should be sure that my answer is still useful in any case, because you want a responsive UI, am I mistaken? ;)

Comment: @AlexNewbie And forever, you won't get any alternate solution. Most modern UI frameworks are now fully asynchronous and the main reason to do so is because multi-threading done right avoids blocking the UI